# Prove non-constant, irreducible polynomials are primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to prove the following statement.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. Prove that a non-constant irreducible polynomial in $R[x]$ is primitive.

This is what I have done so far:

Let $f\in R[x]$ be irreducible. Then there exists $g,h\in R[x]$ such that

$f=gh \implies f\sim g$ or $f\sim h$

Wlog, assume $f\sim g \implies h\in R[x]^X$

Let $g=a_nx^n+...+a_0$, where $n>0$

Thus, $C(f)=C(gh)=gcd(ha_n,...,ha_0)$ so $h$ is a common divisor for $f$.

It is at this stage that I don't know how to proceed further with the proof. Any help would be appreciated.